# Speeding up jquery autocomplete with php list

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

Hi I have run into an issue. I have implemented jquerys famous autocomplete and I am creating a list (quite long) from the database to output into the autocomplete feild. But it is taking too long to find the correct value in list. Does anyone know a way I can speed this up??? Here is my jquery:

```
<script>
    $(function() {function log( message ) {$( "#destId" ).val( message );}
        $( "#destinations" ).autocomplete({
            source: "destinos.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "" + ui.item.id :
                    "" + this.value );}});});
    </script>
```

And here is destinos.php:

```
//connect to database
include 'php/dbconn.php';
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends

$qstring = "SELECT Destination as value, DestinationId as id FROM DestinationId WHERE Destination LIKE '%".$term."%'";
//query the database for entries containing the term
    $result = mysql_query($qstring);
//loop through the retrieved values   
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
            $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
            $row['id']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['id']));
            $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
    }
    echo json_encode($row_set);//format the array into json data
```

Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated!

Comment: First you should cache the result in js and second, you should Limit the SQL query to imporve the performance

Comment: Limits probably won't speed up the query that much, it will reduce the data returned, but it wont reduce the amount of work that needs to be done.

Depending how many records you have, the like query may be an issue.

Comment: `exit (json_encode($row_set));` - won't make a big difference to performance but `exit()` is generally good practice for ajax returns, to ensure you don't get a rogue line feed or anything else on the end of the intended string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start off looking at the DB aspects.

First, you need to make sure you have an index on `Destination`.

Second, you ought to consider using a `LIMIT`, say 10 or 20 rows.  In an autocomplete, in most cases you don't need that many results to display at one time. The match count will decrease as the user continues typing fairly quickly.

Third, you should use proper mysql escape on `$term` variable before querying with it.

The rest looks pretty straightforward.

Comment: thank you this helped a lot... limiting the rows really sped things up!

Answer (score 3):

You most likely need to speed up your database query. You'll have to do a couple of things to do that.

1. Make sure your `Destination` field has an index on it.
2. Unless you absolutely must match from the middle of the string, drop the leading `%` from your LIKE query to enable the index to be used. MySQL cannot effectively use the index with the leading wildcard.
3. If you must leave the leading `%` then set `minLength` to 3 in your jQuery. This will allow MySQL to use an optimizing algorithm on the pattern.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html